# I want to exchange the values of map as follows but its not working

Tags: c++, oop, stl

here i is a pointer so that I can increment and decrement too, but it's not working if I do minus operations as I mentioned in the code

```
for(auto i = soldier.begin();i!=soldier.end();i++){

        int temp1 = i->first;
        int temp2 = i->second;

        i->first = (i-temp2)->first;
        i->second = (i-temp2)->second;

        (i-temp2)->first = temp1;
        (i-temp2)->second = temp2;

    }
```

Comment: you can't do `i->first = (i-temp2)->first;`, you can't change keys of map during iteration over it

Comment: then is there any other way to do it

Comment: I don't quite understand what "exchange" means in map, what do you want to exchange? In `map`, access is done through keys, and you should not use it with indices.

Comment: Another thing, Map value type is `std::pair<const Key, T>`. Since `Key` is const, you should not modify it.

Comment: swap is used to swap two maps, here i have only one map and i want to swap its items @Anirban166

Comment: To be more precise: A `std::map` associates a key witha value, swapping keys _and_ values is completely useless. For example: key1=>value1 and key2=> value2, then you swap both, and end up with the _exact same_ association. This sound like an [XY-problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: Just to be clear, I assume you want to exchange both values and keys (the question says values, but then in your code you intend to swap keys using iterator to `first` as well) - which isn't possible for an `std::map`. I agree with @churill here, even though somehow you could swap keys and values both, swapping them together would make zero sense as the relative key-value pair would be intact, just the ordering of the elements in map changes.

Answer (score 1):

> here i is a pointer so that I can increment and decrement too, but it's not working if I do minus operations

`i` in your code is an iterator, not a pointer. You cannot decrement a forward iterator.

Following your objective as per question title, you can only swap the values pertaining to keys in your map `soldier` by creating iterators to iterate through the map in search of two keys using `std::map::find()` and then swap using `std::swap()`:

```cpp
std::map<DT1, DT2> soldier;

// insert elements (key,value)

// create iterators over the associative map container with your required data types for <key,value> :

const std::map<DT1, DT2>::iterator i1 = soldier.find(key1);
const std::map<DT1,DT2>::iterator i2 = soldier.find(key2);

// you can use auto as well:
//  auto i1 = soldier.find(key1);
//  auto i2 = soldier.find(key2); 

if ((i1 != soldier.end()) && (i2 != soldier.end()))
   { std::swap(i1->second, i2->second);
   }
```

This will swap the values of the corresponding keys in between `key1` and `key2` in your map. You haven't mentioned the data types (nor is it shown in code) used for the key-value pairs in your map so am providing a generalized answer with data types `DT1` and `DT2`.

Note that:

- Using `std::map::find` searches for a key (`find(const key& key)`) and can't be used with values.
- You cannot use an iterator to swap two keys. Also its pointless to swap both keys and values (as mentioned by churill as well) as that would mean your just changing the order of `<key,value>` pairs.

---

An example with a map of `<int ,std::string>` key-value pairs:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <map>
int main()
{
   std::map<int,std::string> soldier;
   soldier[1]="Soldier1";
   soldier[2]="Soldier2";

   const std::map<int ,std::string>::iterator i1 = soldier.find(1);
   const std::map<int ,std::string>::iterator i2 = soldier.find(2);

   if ((i1 != soldier.end()) && (i2 != soldier.end()))
   { std::swap(i1->second, i2->second);
   }

  std::map<int,std::string>::iterator it;
  for(it=soldier.begin(); it!=soldier.end(); ++it)
     std::cout<<it->first<<" "<<it->second<<"\n";

     // 1 Soldier2
     // 2 Soldier1

  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just swap the element, you only need operator[], but you should be sure there is the element:

```
map<int, int> m;
m.insert(std::pair<int, int>(1,100));
m.insert(std::pair<int, int>(2,1000));

// change
int temp = m[1];
m[1] = m[2];
m[2] = temp;
```